# Adding custom grouped fields in SugarCRM

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I need to create a custom field Contact in Sugar CRM.

The field will contain 2 inputs and one select box. And the whole thing should be replicated upon clicking the Add button.

I'm new to Sugar CRM and wondering if I can add the field.

Every comment or answer will appreciate. 
Thanks in advance.

---

This is the field that I need to add

```html
<img src="https://imageshack.com/i/id92zCAAp" border="0">
```

Comment: its is possible, with enterprise edition i think but not in community edition.

Comment: @EuphoriaGrogi - i've made a custom data type for this, just like the address data type. But was not able to group them. Is there any possibility ?

Comment: wait ill check my code how did do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry i will paste the code here, so it can be formatted nicely.

I did it like this,
In my editviewdefs file i added a custom field with the following definition :

```
array (
        'name' => 'status_info_fieldset_c',
        'label' => 'LBL_STATUS_INFO_FIELDSET',
        'customCode' => '<fieldset id = "statInfoFieldSet">
                            <legend>Status Information</legend>
                        </fieldset>',
      ),
```

I override the field and added a customCode, this is the container of the fields.

To group the fields i use js to modify the DOM elements specifically changing the position of the elements like this ,

```
// Copy stat info buttons to fieldset
    var statInfoBtnTdParentOld = $('#changeStatusBtn').parent().prev();
    var statInfoBtnTdOld = $('#changeStatusBtn').parent();
    var statInfoBtnTdParent = statInfoBtnTdParentOld.clone();
    var statInfoBtnTd = statInfoBtnTdOld.clone();
    var statInfoBtnTr = $('<tr></tr>');
    statInfoBtnTr.append(statInfoBtnTdParent);
    statInfoBtnTr.append(statInfoBtnTd);
    statInfoBtnTdParentOld.parent().remove();
```

It depends on how u do it, but I just moved the elements inside the container.

Comment: thanks, i created a custom element and my need is met :D